# Decompressing text in C#

Tags: c#, zip, gzip, compression

I have an issue which I am banging my head against, I am trying to decompress text in this format:

```
eJx7v3t/QWJxcXl+UQoAJ94F3Q==
```

The problem I am having is that it works awesome on this site:
http://www.unit-conversion.info/texttools/compress/

But I can't seem to get it to work with C#, I have tried Gzip and Zip, but it they both throw invalid data errors.

```
using (Stream fs = GenerateStreamFromString("eJx7v3t/QWJxcXl+UQoAJ94F3Q=="))
{
    using (ZipArchive zip = new ZipArchive(fs, ZipArchiveMode.Read))
    {
        //Do stuff
    }
}

public Stream GenerateStreamFromString(string s)
{
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
    writer.Write(s);
    writer.Flush();
    stream.Position = 0;
    return stream;
}
```

it thows an error on the ZipArchive line for the invalid data, it should decompress to "password" but I am unsure why it wont work.

If anyone knows of why or another library that will work, I would love to know!

Thanks!

**EDIT**

I tried the LZW algorithm with no luck, I figured it was zip because the header stated it was gzipped, but I am not sure how the data is compressed due to lack of documentation.

here is my LZW example code.

```
byte[] decodedBytes = Convert.FromBase64String("eJx7v3t/QWJxcXl+UQoAJ94F3Q==");
String text = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decodedBytes);

SharpLZW.LZWDecoder test = new SharpLZW.LZWDecoder();
string testval = test.Decode(text);
```

Decode is where I get the error, I tried with and without Base64 conversion, also with every type of encoding I could think of.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure the string is compressed using Zip ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that is not a ZIP archive. It appears to be base64 encoded, striping that off leaves a set of bytes that do not start "PK" as all ZIP archives do.

Comment: Its compressed using LZW, not zip or gzip. You'll need an LZW algorithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a Base-64 encoding of a *zlib* stream, not gzip, nor zip.  You can use [zlib](http://zlib.net/) to decode it.  It decompresses to `ef bb bf 70 61 73 73 77 6f 72 64`.  (The last eight bytes are "password".)

A quick perusal of the documentation indicates that .NET doesn't have a zlib decoder.  You could write your own zlib header and trailer processing code using RFC 1950, and then the DeflateStream class to decompress the raw compressed data.  Though you probably [shouldn't use .NET for compression](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9472049/1180620).

I would recommend looking at [DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/).

Comment: AH! it works, out of curiosity, how did you know it was zlib? did you just try it to find it?

Comment: I could tell by looking at the first two bytes after decoding the base64.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your compressed text is in Base64 string, you can try first base64 to binary conversation and then try the zip library.

Answer (score 1):

The website you link to claims the compression algorithm it uses is unix `compress`.

> Compress is a Unix based compress program. Once a file is compressed using Compress, you can restore the file to its original state with the uncompress utility. Uncompress restores attributes of a compressed file

A [brief bit of research](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compress) leads to the conclusion this is LZW compression.

> Compress is a Unix shell compression program based on the LZW compression algorithm.

You need a .NET implementation of this - [SharpLZW](http://sharplzw.sourceforge.net/) was the first I found.

Comment: AH! I can't believe I didn't notice that bit of text, I am embarrassed to say I don't know much about compression types, I will try this!

Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work for me, with and without base64 conversion, and I tried it with every type of encoding with base64, no luck.

Answer (score 1):

`eJx7v3t/QWJxcXl+UQoAJ94F3Q==` looks like a base64-encoded string. You need to decode this with the [proper method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.frombase64string%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) before trying to uncompress it.

```
byte[] decodedBytes = Convert.FromBase64String("eJx7v3t/QWJxcXl+UQoAJ94F3Q==");
```

Unfortunately, there's still a problem: the compressed data is not a zip archive. As [Ron Beyer pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30056353/decompressing-text-in-c-sharp#comment48227644_30056353), it's LZW compression. [SharpLZW](http://sharplzw.sourceforge.net/) is one example of a library that can read that in .Net.

Answer (score 0):

The compress program is using the unix compress software

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compress

> Compress is a Unix shell compression program based on the LZW compression algorithm.[1] Compared to more modern compression utilities such as gzip and bzip2, compress performs faster and with less memory usage, at the cost of a significantly lower compression ratio.

I have searched around for some prebuilt libraries and have found http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6838/LZW-Compression Since th algorithm is actually in the public domain you could build it yourself for fun. :D A link to the implementation is: http://warp.povusers.org/EfficientLZW/

Answer (score 0):

I think you have `Base64` Encoding not a Zip-Format. Try something like this:

```
var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String("eJx7v3t/QWJxcXl+UQoAJ94F3Q==");
var text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes);
```

I have no idea if ASCII encoding is the right choice here, because the decoded text is:

> `x?{?{Abqqy~Q '??`

Maybe you have to use zip with that.

Comment: ASCII is obviously not right, as the both the question & linked website say the decoded text is 'password'.