# .NET DeflateStream vs linux zlib difference

Tags: .net, compression, zlib

I need cross-platform compression/decompression between Windows and Ubuntu. As I understand, starting .NET 4.5, class DeflateStream uses zlib as the compression libraries. I have written two small test programs to compress data, one in C# running on Windows and the other in 'C' running on Ubuntu. The .NET platform is 4.5.2.

C# code is using CompressionLevel.Optimal

C code is using Z_BEST_COMPRESSION

Here are the results:

```
Input bytes: {9, 12, 13}
C# output: {227, 228, 225, 5, 0};
C output:  {120, 218, 227, 228, 225, 5, 0, 0, 67, 0, 35}
```

As you can see, the length of compressed data in C# is 5 bytes where as in C is 11 bytes. It seems 'C' zlib is adding 2 extra bytes in header and 4 extra bytes in footer.

If needed, I can share the code. However, it is taken from standard examples that you see on the net and there is nothing special about the code.

Am I missing something? Is there a way to fix it? If the header and the footer always stay the same, perhaps I can always add the additional bytes. Regards.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, you need to understand that there are three possible formats that zlib can generate. They are raw deflate (RFC 1951), a zlib stream which is raw deflate wrapped in a zlib header and trailer (RFC 1950), and a gzip stream which is raw deflate wrapped in a gzip header and trailer (RFC 1952). Your C# code is generating a raw deflate stream, whereas your C code is generating a zlib stream.

You have not shown your code, but you can easily use zlib (in your C code) to produce a raw deflate stream, as `DeflateStream` does. Unfortunately, there is no class in NET 4.5 to produce a zlib stream (in your C# code). However, you can easily create your own zlib header and trailer to wrap the raw deflate stream with. (See the RFC.)

However I would highly recommend that you not use the NET 4.5 zlib interface routines at all. Use [DotNetZip](https://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/) instead, which provides an interface to the full functionality of zlib, and more, and most importantly does not have bugs like in NET 4.5 that Microsoft has said that they [will not fix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9460354/1180620)!

Comment: +1 for avoiding MS implementations. The .NET GZipStream has a bug where it cannot process a file with multiple gzip streams; it only decompresses the first stream.

Comment: Since .NET 6 there is a [ZLibStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.zlibstream?view=net-6.0).

Answer (score 2):

Turns out this is a very old incompatibility problem between DeflateStream and zlib as mentioned here: https://tlzprgmr.wordpress.com/2010/03/17/net-deflatestreamzlib-compatibility/

Essentially, DeflateStream does not add the required header or footer to the compressed data. Regards.