# Convert Byte to Image jpg

Tags: c#, image, drawing, memorystream

i have a problem with convert byte[] to .jpg file.
When I try to convert byte, I got a exception in this method:

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes, 0, bytes.Length))
{
   ms.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
   Image image = Image.FromStream(ms, true, false);
}
```

Exception:

> The parameter is invalid in System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(Stream stream, Boolean useEmbeddedColorManagement, Boolean validateImageData)

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

Solution<sup>*</sup>: Remove the line: `ms.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);`

<sub>* If this doesn't work, the `bytes` array doesn't contain valid image data.</sub>

---

Reason:

This line initializes a `MemoryStream` with the bytes in a byte array. It will start the stream at position 0 (the beginning):

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes, 0, bytes.Length))
```

and in your case it can be simplified to:

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
```

This line then writes the same bytes into the stream. It will leave your stream at position `bytes.Length` (the end):

```
ms.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
```

This line will try to read an image from the stream starting at the current position (the end). Since 0 bytes don't make an image, it fails giving you the exception:

```
Image image = Image.FromStream(ms, true, false);
```

---

As noted by Jimi, it might be better wrapping this up into a method:

```
public static Image ImageFromByteArray(byte[] bytes)
{
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
    using (Image image = Image.FromStream(ms, true, true))
    {
        return (Image)image.Clone();
    }
}
```

The reason for using `Clone()` is that it can cause trouble saving the image if the original stream has been disposed of.

Comment: Just a suggestion, to avoid headaches. It would be better to convert this to a method and return the Image this way: `ms.Position = 0; `using (Image image = Image.FromStream(ms, true)) { return (Image)image.Clone(); }`. The Image should be detached from the Stream (which is immediately disposed of when exiting the `using` block). Or declare the `Image` object outside the `using` block and assign the cloned Image to it.

Comment: Ok, thanks but still have a problem. I convert to Byte this string: "0x78DAED7A6758934BB776A8B211...." and I have the same exception "Parameter is invalid"... Do you have any solution for this situation?

Comment: @Mear your image data is likely valid. If you can provide it via a site like pastebin I can take a look if you like.

Comment: That doesn't appear to be a valid image format. If I convert it to a binary file and open it with a hex editor, I can't see any kind of image header. Where did you get this data?

Comment: In details this file in topic I have "OLYMPUS DIGITAL CAMERA" and property compressed bits/pixel set to 2. Maybe this is a problem?

Comment: Do you have the original file? or just the byte data?

Comment: No, I have only byte array. I received information, that this by is compressed by Zlib but I don't know how to decompress this array and save as .jpg file...Somebody know how to do this?

Comment: "compressed by Zlib" - this is a critically important piece of information.

Comment: You'll need to decompress the byte array using something similar to what is mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41238898/c-decompress-a-stream-using-zlib).