# Powershell ungzip file is not yielding complete result

Tags: .net, powershell, stream, gzip

I was trying to write a powershell script to unzip gziped files. This scripts works perfectly on small files, on larger files (dozen MBs of unzipped size) it is producing an incomplete result.

```
PSVersion 4.0
WSManStackVersion 3.0
SerializationVersion 1.1.0.1
CLRVersion 4.0.30319.18052
BuildVersion 6.3.9600.16406
PSCompatibleVersions {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0}
PSRemotingProtocolVersion 2.2
```

There is no error raised, and it just looks like the scripts completes smoothly. When unzipping with 7z the file is complete. Any idea why this might be happening?

```
$infile = "somefile.gz"
$outfile = ($infile -replace '\.gz$','.xml')

$input = New-Object System.IO.FileStream $inFile, ([IO.FileMode]::Open), ([IO.FileAccess]::Read), ([IO.FileShare]::Read)
$output = New-Object System.IO.FileStream $outFile, ([IO.FileMode]::Create), ([IO.FileAccess]::Write), ([IO.FileShare]::None)
$gzipStream = New-Object System.IO.Compression.GzipStream $input, ([IO.Compression.CompressionMode]::Decompress), true

$buffer = New-Object byte[](0x1000)

while(($read = $gzipstream.Read($buffer, 0, $buffer.Length)) -gt 0){
       $output.Write($buffer, 0, $read)
    }

$gzipStream.Close()
$output.Close()
$input.Close()
```

Comment: This problem seems to be identical to this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1590846/net-gzipstream-compress-and-decompress-problem unfortunatelly any suggeston listed there did not fix it.