# Zip files using vb.net and System.IO.Compression (.Net 4.5)

Tags: vb.net, zip

Given these 2 files:  c:\folder1\test.txt  and  c:\folder2\test.txt

What is the best way to create a zip file (c:\test.zip) and add the 2 files and include the directory structure, using .Net 4.5 System.IO.Compression on VB.NET?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

the answer was located on the site here

[.NET GZipStream compress and decompress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1590846/net-gzipstream-compress-and-decompress-problem)

```
      public static bool Test()
        {
        string sample = "This is a compression test of microsoft .net gzip compression method and            decompression methods";

        System.Text.ASCIIEncoding encoding = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();

        byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(sample);

        // Compress.
        GZipStream hgs;
        byte[] cmpData;

        using(MemoryStream cmpStream = new MemoryStream())
        using(hgs = new GZipStream(cmpStream, CompressionMode.Compress))
        {
            hgs.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

            cmpData = cmpStream.ToArray();
        }

        using(MemoryStream decomStream = new MemoryStream(cmpData))
        using(hgs = new GZipStream(decomStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
        {
            hgs.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
        }

        string sampleOut = encoding.GetString(data);

        bool result = String.Equals(sample, sampleOut);
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: I was actually looking for a way to create a *.ZIP compressed file, not a *.GZ file. Thanks for your response

Comment: well take a look at this article hope it helps http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/381661/Creating-Zip-Files-Easily-in-NET